# How should XCOM games be tagged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Today a [question came in](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/52276/3062) about *X-COM: UFO Defense*. It was tagged with [x-com-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-com-series) and [strategy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy).

We do have a tag for this game, [ufo-defense](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ufo-defense), but I'm guessing that the user didn't find it because he was looking for the name the game is commonly referred to as... simply X-COM.

Looking at the questions that use the [ufo-defense](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ufo-defense) tag, three of the five unnecessarily have the [x-com-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-com-series) tag as well. If you count the one referenced above, which I already fixed, that would have made 4 of the 5 questions about *X-COM: UFO Defense* that had the [x-com-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-com-series) tag. There are a few questions whose only tag is [x-com-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-com-series), but they're clearly questions about a specific game, not the series as a whole. It implies to me that people start putting in a tag for their questions, their inclination is to start typing 'x-com" and they're not finding the [ufo-defense](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ufo-defense) tag.

Note that *X-COM: Terror From the Deep* uses the tag [x-com-tftd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-com-tftd). I didn't see any tags yet for *X-COM: Apocalypse*, *X-COM: Enforcer*, or *X-COM: Interceptor*, though I did find a question for at least one of those which was asked under the tag [x-com-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-com-series).

There are two new X-COM games slated for release this year, and I think that "X-COM" is an important part of the tag. However, they didn't pick terribly distinct names.

- One, a first-person shooter, is simply named ***XCOM***.
- The other, a remake/re-imagining of *X-COM: UFO Defense* (also known as *XCOM: Enemy Unknown*) is simply going to be called ***XCOM: Enemy Unknown***. Hooray for name collision.

Comment: FYI: `UFO-Defense` has `Enemy-Unknown` as a tag synonym.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My proposal would be to retag [ufo-defense](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ufo-defense) as [x-com-ufo-defense](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-com-ufo-defense).

While we're at it, I'd retag [xcom-tftd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xcom-tftd) as [x-com-terror-from-deep](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-com-terror-from-deep), since "TFTD" isn't particularly google-friendly.

The new games would be tagged [xcom](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xcom) and [xcom-enemy-unknown](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xcom-enemy-unknown) (note the lack of hyphen, just as in the title), which may lead to confusion, but I'm not sure of a good way around it.

Comment: -1; The problem with this is that the "-" between X and COM is **highly relevant**. The original games are X-COM. The remakes and reimaginings are XCOM (no hyphen).

Comment: @RavenDreamer Fair enough, and I was on the fence about it myself. Answer updated.

Comment: I have already created an xcom-enemy-unknown tag, when I asked a couple of xcom questions earlier today. Sorry didn't see this meta post.

Comment: @pixel Works out great, since that's the tag we were going to use anyway! Most of the other stuff has already been changed.

Comment: Fine... created a tag wiki entry for the new tag

Comment: The consistency for [xcom] vs [x-com] seems to have eroded over time...